# spring IoC: where to put ComponentScan

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ioc

Here my spring configurer:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@Slf4j
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("Web security performing");

        http
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

        log.info("Web security performed");
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, it's never reached.

Here my application class:

```java
@ComponentScan({
    "cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.core.domain.mpi",
    "cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.core.repository"
})
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = JmxAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ProjectApplication {
```

As you can see, `@ComponentScan` is placed on main `ProjectApplication` class.

I've realized that when I remove `@ComponentScan` from my main `ProjectApplication` class, my `WebSecurityConfiguration` is detected.

When it's present, `WebSecurityConfiguration` is ignored.

Any ideas?

Comment: `@EnableWebSecurity` has `@Configuration` so `@Configuration` is redundant. does Spring successfully pick it? could you test `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.app.security")` also

Comment: I think the problem arises on `@ComponentScan` on my `ApiApplication` class. I think it's modifing where to find classes. I'm editing post...

Answer (score 0):

`SpringBootApplication` without specifying `@ComponentScan` by default scan all classes in the current and those that are located in subpackages for picking `Beans` and `Configuration` and other stuffs. if you specify

```
@ComponentScan({
    "cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.core.domain.mpi",
    "cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.core.repository"
})
```

then only `cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.core.domain.mpi` and `cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.core.repository` and their subpackages will be scanned for beans. so try to put the class which contains  `@SpringBootApplication` in the root of your project or use `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {'package1', 'package2'})` to specify packages that have to be scanned.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rely on spring boot default conventions first:

Assuming you've placed `ProjectApplication` in the `com.mycompany.myapp` package
You can:

1. Remove the `@ComponentScan` annotation from it
2. Place `WebSecurityConfiguration` class in the same package `com.mycompany.myapp` or any package beneath it: Example: `com.mycompany.myapp.web.security.config`.

When spring boot application starts by default it has a very well defined policies of what should be scanned, so it scans the package of the application itself (the package where the file annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` resides) and the packages beneath it.

You can alter this behavior with `@ComponentScan` , but then you might have issues in spring boot driven tests. So without a reason I don't think you should really go there. Of course, if you have an actual reason of altering the default component scanning policies, please share so that our colleagues/me could try to come up with a solution.

Comment: What about if you need component from a third library? Which is the best place to locate it and scan those other classes?

Comment: In this case these libraries implement a "bridge". This is called "starter". You put this starter as a dependency and it automatically loads the configurations provided by this starter. Technically it searches for `META-INF/spring.factories` file that contains a "pointer" on the configuration that should be loaded. These mechanism is known as "auto-configuration" in spring boot. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html or https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter